# react native app is stuck on port 80:81 and won't load anything, only a green bar appears on top of the view

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu

After running the command "react-native run-android" I get this output on the terminal

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 59s
46 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 44 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
8081
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.shoppinglist/.MainActivity }
```

But the app is stuck on localhost: 8081 and I tried entering the IP address with port 8081 manually by going into the settings and editing the "debug server host & port for the device" option as well. But still, it gets the same issue again and again. Any help would really be appreciated. Similar questions have been asked already but believe me I tried every tip out there but nothing seems to work in my case.

[image: I have added the screenshot below for a better reference]

Comment: Probably an issue with lack of resource

Comment: my system has 10gb ram

Comment: What do the console logs say?

Comment: I used the "react-native log-android" command and got stuck at "info Starting logkitty"